# error while loading shared libraries: libicui18n.so.42

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, icu, wkhtmltoimage, imgkit

I am using imagekit gem for one of my projects to create image from html. Imagekit uses wkhtmltoimage to generate image from html.

I have installed wkhtmltoimage using `gem install wkhtmltoimage-binary`. But when I try running the example `/usr/bin/wkhtmltoimage --help` I am getting following error:

`/usr/bin/wkhtmltoimage: error while loading shared libraries: libicui18n.so.42: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`.

I am running my Ruby on Rails 4 project on Centos 6.6 server.

Please suggest.

Comment: what operating system are you using. it appears the the binary is linked against a version of QT that you don't have on your system.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I am using centos 6.6.

Comment: you need to install libicu , google suggests `libicu-4.2.1-12.el6.x86_64.rpm` is what you need.  Might be in base, might be in the EPL, no sure. But installing that should fix the linker error.

Comment: For a similar problem on CentOS I could fix it by downloading the libicu from [https://www.rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=libicui18n.so.42()(64bit)] and adding the extracted library files to the library class path of the program that needed it.